# In Angular child's change event does not fire when parent element has click event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table which has `click` event on row and `change` event on some of its columns. When I toggle the slider the `change` event does not fires instead it fires `click` event of parent element.

P.S. I have already has `click` event on one of column which works perfectly fine.

Below is the code

```
<table #table id="angulartable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
             class="table table-responsive display dt-responsive table-hover row-border hover table-striped list-table nodatatable">
        <thead class="gridHeader">
          <tr>
            <th width="10%">{{'CAN_BE_ORDERED' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%">{{'DISH_CODE' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="20%">{{'DISH_DETAILS' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="10%">{{'CATEGORY' | translate}}</th>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="4" width="14%">{{'PRICE' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%">{{'STATUS' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%" class="text-right" *ngxPermissionsOnly="deleteMenuOfferings"></th>
          </tr>          
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let dish of dishes; let i=index" class="pointer-cls" (click)="goToDetails(dish.Id)">
            <td width="10%" class="position-relative">
              <mat-slide-toggle [name]="i" 
              (change)="updateDishCanOrderStatus(dish, $event)"
                [(ngModel)]="dish.CanOrder">
              </mat-slide-toggle>              

            </td>
            <td width="8%">{{dish.DishCode}}</td>
            <td class="dish_name" width="20%">
              <span class="pl-1">
                <span *ngIf="dish.FoodType != 1; else veg;">
                  <img width="20" height="20" src="{{appConstants.nonVegImage}}">
                </span>
                <ng-template #veg>
                  <img width="20" height="20" src="{{appConstants.vegImage}}">
                </ng-template>
                <strong class="pl-2">{{dish.Name}}</strong>
                <span class="font-italic word-break-all dish_ingredients pl-4 ml-2">({{dish.Ingredients}})</span>
                <div class="mt-1 allergy-img">
                  <img width="15" class="ml-1" matTooltip="{{substance.Name}}" *ngFor="let substance of dish.DishSubstances" height="15" src="../../../../../assets/images/allergic-symbols/{{substance.SubstanceType}}.png">
                </div>
              </span>           

            </td>
            <td width="10%">{{dish.CategoryName}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let dummy of [].constructor(4), let x = index" width="14%">
              <div class="priceinfo">
                <mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="dish.QuantityPrices[x]" name="canorder_{{x}}"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.QuantityPrices[x].IsOptionOrderable"
                  (change)="makeDishOptionOrderable(dish.QuantityPrices[x].DishQuantityPriceId, dish.Id, dish.QuantityPrices[x].IsOptionOrderable)">
                </mat-slide-toggle><br>
                <label class="mb-0">
                  {{ dish.QuantityPrices[x] ? dish.QuantityPrices[x].Quantity : '' }}
                </label><br>
                <label
                  class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">{{ dish.QuantityPrices[x] ? (dish.QuantityPrices[x].Price | formatCurrency:'EUR') : '' }}</label>
              </div>              
            </td>
            <td>
              <span width="8%"
                    [ngClass]="getStatusColor(dish.Status)">{{dish.Status == 1 ? ('ACTIVE' | translate) : ('INACTIVE' | translate)}}</span>
            </td>
            <td width="8%" class="text-right" *ngxPermissionsOnly="deleteMenuOfferings">
              <a (click)="deleteDish(dish.Id, $event)">{{'DELETE' | translate}}                
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I noticed that first the `click` event of parent element fires and then `change` event of child element fires. So I wrapped the child element in a `DIV` and added a `click` event like this `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()"`.

```
<table #table id="angulartable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
             class="table table-responsive display dt-responsive table-hover row-border hover table-striped list-table nodatatable">
        <thead class="gridHeader">
          <tr>
            <th width="10%">{{'CAN_BE_ORDERED' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%">{{'DISH_CODE' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="20%">{{'DISH_DETAILS' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="10%">{{'CATEGORY' | translate}}</th>
            <th class="text-center" colspan="4" width="14%">{{'PRICE' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%">{{'STATUS' | translate}}</th>
            <th width="8%" class="text-right" *ngxPermissionsOnly="deleteMenuOfferings"></th>
          </tr>          
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let dish of dishes; let i=index" class="pointer-cls" (click)="goToDetails(dish.Id)">
            <td width="10%" class="position-relative">
              <div (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" class="width-max-content">
                <mat-slide-toggle [name]="i" (change)="updateDishCanOrderStatus(dish)" [(ngModel)]="dish.CanOrder">
                </mat-slide-toggle>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="8%">{{dish.DishCode}}</td>
            <td class="dish_name" width="20%">
              <span class="pl-1">
                <span *ngIf="dish.FoodType != 1; else veg;">
                  <img width="20" height="20" src="{{appConstants.nonVegImage}}">
                </span>
                <ng-template #veg>
                  <img width="20" height="20" src="{{appConstants.vegImage}}">
                </ng-template>
                <strong class="pl-2">{{dish.Name}}</strong>
                <span class="font-italic word-break-all dish_ingredients pl-4 ml-2">({{dish.Ingredients}})</span>
                <div class="mt-1 allergy-img">
                  <img width="15" class="ml-1" matTooltip="{{substance.Name}}" *ngFor="let substance of dish.DishSubstances" height="15" src="../../../../../assets/images/allergic-symbols/{{substance.SubstanceType}}.png">
                </div>
              </span>           

            </td>
            <td width="10%">{{dish.CategoryName}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let dummy of [].constructor(4), let x = index" width="14%">
              <div class="priceinfo">
                <mat-slide-toggle *ngIf="dish.QuantityPrices[x]" name="canorder_{{x}}"
                  [(ngModel)]="dish.QuantityPrices[x].IsOptionOrderable"
                  (change)="makeDishOptionOrderable(dish.QuantityPrices[x].DishQuantityPriceId, dish.Id, dish.QuantityPrices[x].IsOptionOrderable)">
                </mat-slide-toggle><br>
                <label class="mb-0">
                  {{ dish.QuantityPrices[x] ? dish.QuantityPrices[x].Quantity : '' }}
                </label><br>
                <label
                  class="mb-0 font-weight-bold">{{ dish.QuantityPrices[x] ? (dish.QuantityPrices[x].Price | formatCurrency:'EUR') : '' }}</label>
              </div>              
            </td>
            <td>
              <span width="8%"
                    [ngClass]="getStatusColor(dish.Status)">{{dish.Status == 1 ? ('ACTIVE' | translate) : ('INACTIVE' | translate)}}</span>
            </td>
            <td width="8%" class="text-right" *ngxPermissionsOnly="deleteMenuOfferings">
              <a (click)="deleteDish(dish.Id, $event)">{{'DELETE' | translate}}                
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the (change) is supposed to be in [change], try and let us know if it works

Comment: No, it doesn't work. () is used for event binding and [] property binding and here we need event binding